# Как настроить automapper для маппинга вложенных сущностей?

Tags: c#, automapper

Всем привет. У меня есть две сущности ToDo, подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить для них automapper. Сейчас из-за User и UserModel ловится исключение.

```
 private IMapper _mapper;
 private void SetupMapper<TFrom, TTo>()
 {
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TFrom, TTo>());
    _mapper = new Mapper(config);
 }

public class ToDoItem
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public string Content  { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted  { get; set; }
        public int Importance  { get; set; } 
        public User Creator { get; set; }
        public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    }
public class ToDoModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public int Importance { get; set; }
        public UserModel Creator { get; set; }
        public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: доку читали? https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html

Comment: @tym32167 не нашел, увы. Спасибо большое, проблема решена. Если хотите, можете кинуть ссылку на доки  в качестве ответа, я отмечу решением.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки тут не приветствуются, а расписывать ответ мне некогда. Можете запостить самоответ и его принять.

Comment: @tym32167 не, это если вам рейтинг нужен. Мне все равно, будет ли тут решение.